# Purpose of SetEnv SERVER_ADMIN?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

Why would you use the following directive in .htaccess or httpd.conf:

```
SetEnv SERVER_ADMIN email@domain.com
```

I have a friend who uses a fictitious email address, I guess to avoid spam. What if you don't set anythign, what would Apache server use for this value?

How does this directive differ from the directive:

```
ServerAdmin email@domain.com
```